# How to save a signature captured by svg file (Present in HTML-Form)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using a svg file in a iframe to get the user's Signature , which is implemented in a form,
It works fine, but how can i save the signature at my server ?
Is there any way to catch the data (" the signature" ) either in the same svg file loadable or any image ?

I am using HTML/ Javascript only .

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to read the path data from the svg and then set that value to a hidden field in the form before you submit the form.

Here's a minimal example: http://mcc.id.au/2010/signature.html

Comment: Thanks Mene for the link , I got the path like L1,M2.......
Now how can I save it in server , so that I will be able to retrive that signature again ?

Comment: as i said you'll need a form to transmit the data (or an ajax-request). When using a form: add a hidden field; add an onsubmit handler to the form; in that handler take the path and set the value of the hidden field to it, then continue to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will be implementing the same :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as solution if it was what you were looking for. Does look like you never did this. Having a higher accept-rate will increase the willingness of others to help you.

Comment: Just last question, Any easy way to retrieve that signature back with the format text I have ??
like l1l2m3.....??

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Answer (score -1):

If its really SVG then simply convert it to an XML file and name it with a svg file extension.  The conversion to XML should require little more than an XML pragma on the first line.

Comment: That's for showing a svg, not for reading data from a viewed svg back to the browser and transmit it to the server.

Comment: The SVG data, in this case, is being submitted by a form, so it would be read by the server.

Comment: On submitting the form, The svg data is not being submitted , Any code samples will help !

Comment: Just submit the SVG data as plain text in the value of a text input.